# debugging with monodevelop from client

Tags: c#, debugging, nginx, monodevelop

I have been used to use visual studio to create web apps and other application. Visual studio makes it possible to place a breake point on a method, and activate that breakpoint from the client side. And as soon as that method gets called, the debugging will begin, and you can press next etc to see the different values of the variables.

Circumstances for the past 6 months, have required me to use monodevelop, since I am working on ubuntu. I am using nginx as webserver. Many times I have searced for documentation on how to debug from monodevelop. I have not been able to find any solution, and mono's documentation hasn't helped me so far, unfortunately. So to debug my code, I write to a log, which is killing me.

Has anyone successfully found a way to debug code using monodevelop, and activate that breakpoint from the client? Similar to the way in visual studio, that I just described?

Comment: I thought MonoDevelop supported breakpoints, and there is a play button on the toolbar for starting. Says here "Integrated Debugger" http://www.monodevelop.com/screenshots/

Comment: Yes it is possible to place a breakpoint, but you can't activate that breakpoint from the client by default

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set breakpoints in Mono the same way you do in VS. Verify you have installed all the relevant packages before.

http://www.mono-project.com/archived/guidedebugger/

Comment: I have added a bit more details. I should had mentioned that I want to activate the breakpoint from the client side, like in a browser for example